# Unable to load xml file in Sqlserver:Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code (null)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to load data from xml file in to sql server table column.Tried the below query

```
declare @fileData nvarchar(max)

Select @fileData=BulkColumn
     from OpenRowSet(Bulk 'C:\Testfile\Test.xml', Single_blob ) x;
```

But I am getting the below error

```
 Cannot bulk load because the file "C:Testfile\Test.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).
 Am trying from SSMS in my machine,i dont have access to sql server machine.
```

Comment: Does the SQL Server Service Account have access to `C:\TestFile`?

Comment: Wait, if you don't have access to the SQL Server  machine, how did you get the file `Test.xml` into the folder `Testfile` on it's `C:`??

Comment: Its local path in my machine.Can't we use the local path.Sorry am new to this concept.

Comment: The SQL Server won't be able to access you're local `C:` (or it shouldn't). `'C:\Testfile\Test.xml'` means a file located on the `C:` that the Instance is hosted on. Any file paths provided are always from the perspective of the server, not yours. The reason  the upload is failing is likely because that file doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: To the SQL Server, "C:\" means the C drive of the machine where SQL Server is running. Remember that your SSMS is just a client of the SQL server. It's a bit like looking at the server through the window. Any SQL commands you run are passed to the server (through the window, if you like) and run on the server, not on your machine. SQL Server knows nothing about your local machine. It's a bit similar to how Remote Desktop works, in a way. So if you want SQL to open this file, it must be on the SQL Server machine (or on a fileshare which the server has permission to read from)

Comment: Any other option to load the xml file from the local path?

Comment: Not really, no, at least not from a simple SQL script. Put the file somewhere that SQL Server can see it. Either that or use the manual "import" wizard in SSMS, or see if you can use SSIS to automate it. Or you may be able to use the `bcp` command line utility to achieve it.